# msal-react/browser doesn't initiate login when deployed, works fine locally

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal-react

I have a React app that uses msal-browser & msal-react. I begin to experience issues when my app is deployed (via Azure Web App, Azure Static Web App, and the Azure Static Web App CLI locally). This works fine locally with npm run start however.

The issue is `instance.loginPopup()` and `instance.loginRedirect()` don't initiate any popups or redirects, and instead give these errors:

[image]

[image]

The cookies have a value for `msal.interaction.status` which is always undefined

[image]

I've been following the MS samples closely, and am unsure why this is only happening when deployed.

Here is my code:

**Index.tsx**

```js
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
  msalInstance.initialize().then(() => {
    console.log('Initialised!');

    if (!msalInstance.getActiveAccount() && msalInstance.getAllAccounts().length > 0) {
      msalInstance.setActiveAccount(msalInstance.getAllAccounts()[0]);
    } 

    msalInstance.enableAccountStorageEvents();

    msalInstance.addEventCallback((event: any) => {
      if (event.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS
        ||
        event.eventType === EventType.ACQUIRE_TOKEN_SUCCESS
        ||
        event.eventType === EventType.SSO_SILENT_SUCCESS
      ) {
        const account = event.payload.account;
        msalInstance.setActiveAccount(account);
      }
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error');
    console.log(err);
  })
```

**AuthConfig.tsx**

```js
export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID as string,
    authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
    knownAuthorities: [b2cPolicies.authorityDomain],
    redirectUri: process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: '/',
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE || isEdge || isFirefox
  },
  system: {
    allowNativeBroker: false, 
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
        if (containsPii) {
          return;
        }
        switch (level) {
          case LogLevel.Error:
            console.error(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Info:
            console.info(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Verbose:
            console.debug(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Warning:
            console.warn(message);
            return;
          default:
            return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

**App.tsx**

```js
function App({ msalInstance }: { msalInstance: PublicClientApplication }) {
  return (
    <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
      <SignInSignOut />
      <div>
        Home
      </div>
    </MsalProvider>
  );
}
```

**SignIn.tsx**

```js
const SignIn = () => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();

  const logIn = () => {
    instance.loginRedirect();
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={logIn}>Sign In</button>
  )
};
```

Comment: How are you publishing your code to the azure web app? Is it with build folder or complete project?

Comment: Use the **npm run build** command to build the project, and then run it locally with **npm start**.

Comment: After working with the local output, deploy the build folder to the Azure web app and check.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code and successfully signed in with Azure B2C tenant locally and in the Azure web app.

***Code:***

**Note :** Replace the localhost URL with the web app URL in redirectUri before deployment.
`https://<webapp_name>.azurewebsites.net/`

**msal/AuthConfig.tsx :**

```js
import { Configuration, LogLevel } from '@azure/msal-browser';

export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "<client_ID>" as string,
    authority: 'https://<b2c-tenant>.b2clogin.com/<your-b2c-tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>', 
    knownAuthorities: ['https://<b2c-tenant>.b2clogin.com/<your-b2c-tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>'], 
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/",  //https://<webapp_name>.azurewebsites.net/
    postLogoutRedirectUri: '/',
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
  },
  system: {
    allowNativeBroker: false,
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
        if (containsPii) {
          return;
        }
        switch (level) {
          case LogLevel.Error:
            console.error(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Info:
            console.info(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Verbose:
            console.debug(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Warning:
            console.warn(message);
            return;
          default:
            return;
        }
      },
    },
  },
};
```

***msalInstance.ts :***

```js
import { PublicClientApplication, Configuration, LogLevel, EventType } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { msalConfig } from './msal/AuthConfig';

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
msalInstance.initialize()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Initialized!');

    if (!msalInstance.getActiveAccount() && msalInstance.getAllAccounts().length > 0) {
      msalInstance.setActiveAccount(msalInstance.getAllAccounts()[0]);
    }

    msalInstance.enableAccountStorageEvents();
    msalInstance.addEventCallback((event: any) => {
      if (
        event.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS ||
        event.eventType === EventType.ACQUIRE_TOKEN_SUCCESS ||
        event.eventType === EventType.SSO_SILENT_SUCCESS
      ) {
        const account = event.payload.account;
        msalInstance.setActiveAccount(account);
      }
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error during initialization');
    console.error(err);
  });
export default msalInstance;
```

***components/SignIn.tsx :***

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';

const SignIn: React.FC = () => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const logIn = () => {
    instance.loginRedirect();
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={logIn}>Sign In</button>
  );
};
export default SignIn;
```

***components/App.tsx :***

```js
import React from 'react';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react';
import SignIn from './SignIn';
import { msalConfig } from '../msal/AuthConfig';

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
      <SignIn />
      <div>
        Home
      </div>
    </MsalProvider>
  );
};
export default App;
```

***src/index.tsx :***

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I added the URLs below to the app's Redirect URI as follows:

```
http://localhost:3000/
https://<webapp_name>.azurewebsites.net/
```

[image]

***Output :***

It ran successfully, as shown below:

[image]

I got the output below with the above output URL in the browser. I clicked the Sign In button to sign in, as shown below:

[image]

I successfully signed in with my email ID and password, as shown below.

[image]

I deployed my build folder to the Azure web app, as shown below:

[image]

It deployed successfully, as shown below.

[image]

I got the page below with the web app URL. I clicked the Sign In button to sign in, as shown below:

[image]

I successfully signed in with my email ID and password, as shown below.

[image]